# What are the differences/similarities between naghelp and nagiosplugin, and when would you use one and not the other?

Tags: python, nagios, plugin

I'm reading on `Nagios plugin` creation with Python, and I encountered [naghelp](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-nagios-helpers/downloads/pdf/latest/) and [nagiosplugin](https://nagiosplugin.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/).
To my novice eyes, they look similar.
When would one prefer to use `naghelp` over `nagiosplugin` (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

One apparent difference is in the [naghelp documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-nagios-helpers/downloads/pdf/latest/) itself:

> There is a little difference between a naghelp plugin and a Nagios plugin:

> A naghelp plugin is a python class, a Nagios plugin is a script. To build a Nagios plugin from a naghelp plugin, you
> just have to instantiate a naghelp plugin class and call the run() method...